# Align three images to spread across the page evenly

Tags: css, html, image, center

I have one 'main' div that that is wrapped around three child div's. Each child div holds an image. My goal is for the three images to be evenly aligned across my page. The images are all the same size (200px by 166px). If there is some way to do this without the use of a dozen div's that would be superb. To reiterate my question, I do NOT want all three images centered. I want the left img to be 30 pixels from the left of the page; the right img to be 30 pixels from the right of the page, and I want the center img to be perfectly centered between the two.

#### HTML:

```
    <div id="aboutimages">
        <div id="aboutimgleft">
            <img src="Stylesheets/images/manpc.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="aboutimgcenter">
            <img src="Stylesheets/images/coffee.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="aboutimgright">
            <img src="Stylesheets/images/keyboard.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#aboutimages{
text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
    }

#aboutimgleft img{
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:0px;
    width:250px;
} 

#aboutimgcenter {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 70%;
}

#aboutimgcenter img{
    text-align:center;
    width:250px;
    height:166px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#aboutimgright img{
    float:right;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:0px;
    width:250px;
    height:166px;
}
```

I am desperate for any type of help - this is frustrating the living hell out of me.

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to pull this off, here's one way:

```
#aboutimages {
    position:relative; /* constrain absolutely positioned child elements */
}

#aboutimgleft {
    float:left; /* Float the first element */
    margin-left:30px; /* Here's that 30px you wanted */
} 

#aboutimgcenter {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the second element */
}
#aboutimgright {
    /* easier than float:right, but that could work too with some tweaking */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:30px; /* Here's that other 30px you wanted */
}
```

As long as the images are in those divs, they will be aligned.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KPJP4/

Comment: For some reason, using both your code and my code the image on the right is always out of whack.

Comment: I don't recommend you mix your code with mine, but rather use the code I provided as a base. Here's another version that does use the `<img>` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/KPJP4/1/ If you can show me a demo of the issues you're having with this code I'm happy to help.

Comment: There is no private message system on SO. You can add your URL to your post for reference while the problem still persists, but I can't see how this solution doesn't already fit your requirements exactly. You may need to be sure you don't have other styles interfering.

Comment: OK, I see two issues: 1) Your `#aboutimages` div is not behaving, try adding `float:left;width:100%;` 2) The 3 divs *also* need to have the same width that you specified for your images. That fixed it right up in FF5 for me.

Comment: @Evan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2558/discussion-between-wesley-murch-and-evan)

Comment: This guy is awesome! Thank you so much!! He deserves 100 up-votes for all the extra help he gave me. Amazing. Thank you once again.

Comment: Evan, for the record, now that I know what your layout is really like, you don't need all this. Since you have *everything* fixed width, you could have solved it without any divs at all by simply floating the 3 images and adding some known pixel value `margin-right` to the first two images.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<style type="text/css">
#aboutimgleft, #aboutimgcenter, #aboutimgright {
    float: left; 
    width: 33.33%;
}

#aboutimgleft img {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

#aboutimgcenter {
    text-align: center;
}

#aboutimgright {
    text-align: right;
}

#aboutimgright img {
    margin-right: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Only issue is that 33.33% is not accurate, a 1px gap may appear on the right after the 3rd div.

Comment: That's true. I intended it to be an quick solution that didn't require positioning (since i didn't know what else is going on within the page). Positioning can be used to make it pixel-perfect.

Comment: The funny thing is, he's got individual ids on 3 wrapper divs, fixed width images, and a fixed width layout. This particular issue could have been solved by simple floats and margins, in fact the wrapper divs are not even necessary for a solution that simple to work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this to work is setting the outer wrapper to a certain width and having it set to `text-align: center;` and then having all the divs inside set to `display: inline-block;` and floated respectively. I set up a test page here with your code (simplified a bit): http://jsbin.com/uworex so you can see how it's now working for me.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. What browser and resolution do you have? Here's a slightly different version that uses 100% width for the wrapper instead of 1000px: [http://jsbin.com/uworex/2/](http://jsbin.com/uworex/2/)